# htaccess, how to allow access to a file by only search engines or bots

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I have a sitemap file called links.txt, and I want only search engine/bots to access this file.

How can I do that via htaccess file.

Comment: Generally you can't; you'll need to know all IP addresses that would be used by any search engine's bots that you wish to allow. Other access restriction mechanisms (user agent, for example) are circumventable.

Comment: Just rename it to `links-with-url-nobody-will-ever-guess.txt` and submit that one. Or do you link to the file using some html meta element?

Comment: `robots.txt` is a way to show files to the search engine bots.